# ImageResizer works when testing with Visual Studio - not working on production?

Tags: imageresizer

I have ImageResizer installed via NuGet which is working fine when I run the ASP.Net MVC website from Visual Studio. I can get to the /resizer.debug page and it says all is well.

When I come to publish the site from Visual Studio to the main IIS instance on the same machine, ImageResizer does not work and when I browse to /resizer.debug I get a 404 Not Found error.

I have published the web.config and verified all the image resizer components are in there. Eg:

```
<httpModules><add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" /></httpModules></system.web>
```

The ImageResizer dlls are also in the /bin directory.

However, nothing is happening and the debug page will not display.

Is there something that needs to be done to configure ImageResizer on IIS7 when publishing the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you only configured it for IIS Classic, not IIS7 Integrated mode. There **must** be a `<system.webServer>` element with the module installed.

[From the installation guide](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/install):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
   <configSections>
     <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection,ImageResizer"  requirePermission="false"  />
   </configSections>

   <resizer>
     <!-- Unless you (a) use Integrated mode, or (b) map all requests to ASP.NET, 
          you'll need to add .ashx to your image URLs: image.jpg.ashx?width=200&height=20 -->
     <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" defaultCommands="autorotate.default=true"/>

     <plugins>
       <add name="DiskCache" />
       <!-- <add name="PrettyGifs" /> -->
       <!-- <add name="SimpleFilters" /> -->
       <!-- <add name="S3Reader" /> -->
     </plugins>  
   </resizer>

   <system.web>
     <httpModules>
       <!-- This is for IIS7/8 Classic Mode and Cassini-->
       <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule"/>
     </httpModules>
   </system.web>

   <system.webServer>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
     <modules>
       <!-- This is for IIS7/8 Integrated mode -->
       <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule"/>
     </modules>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```